# Converting a Pandas dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dateframe:

```
+-----------+-------+---------+
| kpi_name  | coeff | measure |
+-----------+-------+---------+
| messi     | 2     | DoD     |
| ronaldo   | 1.5   | MTD     |
| del_piero | 2     | MTD     |
+-----------+-------+---------+
```

I need to convert this to a dictionary like :

```
{'MTD':[{'KPI':'ronaldo', 'measure':'1.5'}, {'KPI:':'messi', 'measure':'2'],
 'DoD':['KPI':'messi', 'measure':'1.4']}
```

I am trying:

```
a = df.groupby('measure').apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('list')).to_dict()
```

My output:

```
{'MTD': {'kpi_name': ['ronaldo', 'del_piero'], 'coeff': [1.5, 2.0], 'measure': ['MTD', 'MTD']}, 'DoD': {'kpi_name': ['messi'], 'coeff': [2.0], 'measure': ['DoD']}}
```

Thx a lot of help!

Comment: Please explain more your desired output. How does *MTD* relate to *messi* being on different rows. And where does 1.4 derive?

Comment: @Parfait Important for me groping by measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into [slicing dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) and [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) `T` for future reference.

Given a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KPI':['messi', 'ronaldo', 'del_piero'],\
                   'coeff':[2, 1.5, 2], \
                   'measure':['DoD', 'MTD', 'MTD']})
```

You can use the following lambda function

```
df.groupby('measure').apply(lambda x: list(x[['KPI','coeff']].T.to_dict().values())).to_dict()
```

To achieve your expected output

```
{'DoD': [{'KPI': 'messi', 'coeff': 2.0}],
 'MTD': [{'KPI': 'ronaldo', 'coeff': 1.5}, {'KPI': 'del_piero', 'coeff': 2.0}]}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for solution! There small question, why we use double brackets **x[['KPI','coeff']]**

Comment: This solution is inefficient due to the apply overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary comprehension with `GroupBy`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'kpi_name': ['messi', 'ronaldo', 'del_piero'],
                   'coeff': [2, 1.5, 2],
                   'measure': ['DoD', 'MTD', 'MTD']})

res = {k: grp.to_dict(orient='records') for k, grp in df.groupby('measure')}

print(res)

{'DoD': [{'kpi_name': 'messi', 'coeff': 2.0, 'measure': 'DoD'}],
 'MTD': [{'kpi_name': 'ronaldo', 'coeff': 1.5, 'measure': 'MTD'},
         {'kpi_name': 'del_piero', 'coeff': 2.0, 'measure': 'MTD'}]}
```